# OpenLayers 3 Features Connected

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am attempting to draw some circles on a map. I am creating the circles as features, then placing them in a layer. The issue I am having is that there is a line connecting each of the different features. What is causing the features to be connected?

```
// Generate some rings
var radius = [1000, 2000];
var features = [];
for(var i = 0; i < radius.length; i++)
{
    features[i] = new ol.Feature( new ol.geom.Circle(center, radius[i] / ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT.m ) );
}

// Add features to new layer.
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: features
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            width: 1,
            color: [0, 0, 255, 1]
        })
    })
});
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Edit: Here is a screenshot of what I am getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/T28Zj.png

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the connecting lines? Your code basically works fine for me, tho I did tweak a couple of things. I'll paste my version below in case it helps.

Comment: I just looked at your s/shot and it is not clear why your code above would cause that. Can you post more of your code? or recreate the problem in plunkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: @sifriday I just checked it on plunker, and it didn't have the connecting lines. The issue was that I had openlayers 3.15.0, and switching to 3.2.1 fixed the issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: splendid, glad you got that fixed. I saw you put this answer below... On StackOverflow it is ok to accept your own answer, and in fact is a good thing: it helps other people know this question has a successful answer, so can I suggest you go ahead and click to accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the connected circles is a bug within openlayers. Updating to the newest version corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me, though I did have to define an initial centre,which I put at [0,0] to match the view I defined for the map. I also added some ol.Map code (you have not supplied this bit in your Q, so maybe the problem is there?)

I used this HTML:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
```

and this JavaScript:

```
var center = [0, 0];
var radius = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000];
var features = [];
for(var i = 0; i < radius.length; i++)
{
    features[i] = new ol.Feature( new ol.geom.Circle(center, radius[i] / ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT.m ) );
}

// Add features to new layer.
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: features
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            width: 1,
            color: [0, 0, 255, 1]
        })
    })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
        layer
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 10
    })
});
```